how do I convert my underscores into whitespaces at the terminal?
Below is my code for a hangman game, but it has a bug. How do I make the code leave the whitespaces on the word list as whitespaces instead of printing it out as an underscore in the terminal? It displays an underscore at the terminal and doesn't break the code after correctly guessing it, which makes the user guess until it breaks by the user failing to guess.
import random

words = ["motherboard", "central processing unit", "power supply", "monitor", "graphics processing unit", "memory", "solid state drive", "mango "]
word = random.choice(words)
guessed_letters = []
incorrect_guesses = 0
max_attempts = 6 

while incorrect_guesses < max_attempts:
    display_word = ''.join(letter if letter in guessed_letters else '_' for letter in word)
    print(f"Word: {display_word}")

    if display_word == word:
        print("Congratulations! You guessed the word.")
        break;
    print(f"Incorrect guesses remaining: {max_attempts - incorrect_guesses}")
    guess = input("Enter a letter: ").lower()

    if len(guess) != 1 or not guess.isalpha():
        print("Please enter a single letter.")
        continue

    if guess in guessed_letters:
        print("You've already guessed that letter.")
        continue

    guessed_letters.append(guess)

    if guess not in word:
        incorrect_guesses += 1
        print(f"Oops! '{guess}' is not in the word.")
    if incorrect_guesses == max_attempts:
        print(f"Sorry, you ran out of guesses. The word was '{word}'.")


You could initialize guessed_letters = [' '] so the spaces are left alone by if letter in guessed_letters

Or you could use if letter == ' ' or letter in guessed_letters

@Barmar but then the rest of the logic needs various updates, too. The code doesn't let you guess a space but requires it to be there, etc.

@tripleee I admit that it's kind of a kludge, and the separate if condition is cleaner. But it's also innocuous, since nothing displays guessed_letters so this extra space will never be noticed. The code already prohibits guessing non-letters.
